# OpenCV Python - cv2.groupRectangles() is returning empty tuple

Tags: python, opencv

I am drawing rectangles around numbers in 2D technical drawings. I am finding the numbers using `cv2.findContours()`. I am trying to group overlapping rectangles using `cv2.groupRectangles()` but when I try to print the `rectList` it is printing ().

`all_rects` is a list of all the rectangles I found using the contours function and is in the form [x,y,w,h].

```
one_rect = []
all_rects = []
for cnt in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    one_rect = [x,y,w,h]
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt) 
    if area < 1000: #if rectangle is very large
        all_rects.append(one_rect)
    else:
        print("area too big")

print(all_rects)


rectList,weights=cv2.groupRectangles(all_rects, 1, 0.2)
print(rectList)
for (mx,my,mw,mh) in rectList:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (mx,my), (mx+mw, my+mh), (0,0,0), 5)
    cv2.imshow("grouped", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I am expecting it to return a list of x,y,w,h points but the `print(rectList)` is returning "()"

Comment: Either `cv2.groupRectangles` is not returning `None` or `print(rectList)` is not printing `()`. Can you show us what is in `weights`?

Comment: what does weights give if you print it?

Comment: ```print(weights) is also printing ()

Comment: Show us the output of `print(all_rects)`